# Is there anyway to keep Visual Studio to keep from holding onto an applications logo when done debugging?

Tags: microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, visual-studio-2012, windows-store

I have a minor problem with Visual Studio 2012.

Basically, I'm constantly iterating through debugging an installed Windows Store application. My problem is that everytime I stop debugging and need to update and reinstall the package, I get an error when trying to reinstall the package.

It goes along the lines of `fails to write to file ....Assets/logo.png`. When I close the instance of Visual Studio that was debugging it, the file becomes unlocked and the package will install fine.

Has anyone else experienced this problem and know of any kind of work around other than restarting Visual Studio?

Comment: Is there any specific reason you reinstall the package each time? I've been debugging my app and I don't need to reinstall each time I make a change or debug the app.

Comment: @Krishna because I work on an obfuscator and that entails unpacking the package, changing around the IL and metadata, and then repacking it. There doesn't appear to be a native way to debug a package without installing it each time.

Comment: interesting. Perhaps you may have to include closing down devenv each time you update the package and start it up again - in your script/process?

Comment: @Krishna this really sucks since we use Windows 8 in a virtual machine on hardware that isn't the best. This adds about 30 seconds to debug each change we make. Hence, this question :)

Comment: understand. How about: stop debugging, copy everything to somewhere else, and do your stuff there? Will you need to update the source again? Perhaps store your output in a subdirectory of the project?

Comment: @Krishna that won't help. The file VS keeps a hold of is in the *installed* package directory. So, moving my package generation somewhere else doesn't help. I'm actually very surprised the uninstall of the package works when Visual Studio keeps it from deleting that file.

Comment: so in the end, did you manage to solve this?